# What is a term for someone who is bad at communicating with other people?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word for someone who is incapable of getting their point across clearly or understanding other people.

I can only think of longer phrases.

e.g.

> Don't worry about Geoff's manner. He's **not a people-person**.

But I'm sure there's a more succinct term.

Comment: Oh, and I'd like to preempt whoever was about to say "Computer Programmer" or suchlike. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does 'inarticulate' work in your context?

Comment: You'll get flagged for answering a question with a question ('Inarticulate' might be a word you find appropriate) (but note that RegDwight had already mentioned 'not articulate').

Answer (score 3):

[*Not well-spoken*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well-spoken) brings the point across without being too offensive. You can euphemize even further and use [*not too eloquent*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eloquent). Conversely, on the other side of the spectrum, there's [*not articulate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/articulate).

If you need a noun, that of course would be *not an orator*.

Answer (score 1):

You could describe the person as being [introverted](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/introverted) or an [introvert](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/introvert) in addition to them being [shy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shy) or socially [timid](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/timid).

Comment: Introverts, shy and socially timid people are not necessarily bad communicators. They just don't like to do it.